# Java Event Listener - Detect when JMenu opens up

Tags: java, swing, listener, event-listener, jmenu

What kind of `EventListener` can I use to get notified when a `JMenu` opens?

For example:
When the user clicks on a `Menu` in the `MenuBar` (or hovers it) and it opens up revealing its content, like a `JCheckBoxMenuItem` or another `JMenu` component.

Comment: @camickr I tried every listener without success, otherwise I would not have asked the question. Isn't that obvious to you?

Comment: `I tried every listener without success,` - then post your code, because it works for me.

Comment: @camickr Thank you, your answer was the solution, just tested it. Why did you delete?

Comment: Because the MenuListener in the JMenu class works. I'm waiting for you to post your [mcve] demonstrating that it does not work. It is the listener to use based on your requirement.

Comment: @camickr Yes, MenuListener works. I tried that listener before posting the question but it did not work but I guess I had an error somewhere in the code.

Comment: That is why an [mcve] should be included with every question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a javax.swing.event.MenuListener instance.
The menuSelected and menuDeselected methods will be invoked when the menu opens and closes respectively.  There is also a menuCanceled method but I haven't figured out how/when/if it is ever called.